# Macro Keys on Logitech Keyboard on Linux

Tags: drivers, keyboard

I have a Logitech G915 Keyboard but I cannot find a way to configure the macro keys because Logitech is not giving support, although I already [asked](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-za/community/posts/6506804176919--LINUXUSERSMATTERS).

How can I use my macro keys in Ubuntu, is there any opensource project that give support to Logitech hardware?

Comment: whatever hid device (I presume it is) should output some string when whatever key is depressed. Start identifying which eventX (of /dev/input) is (are) associated to your keyboard (bootlog and xorg log should help you in that task) then just cat it and depress the key you want. (might be necessary to pipe to od)

Comment: is mapping this keys to the Fs keys, so pressing a macro is the same as pressing and F key, there is no difference between them from the OS point of view

Comment: we don't do hashtags around these parts. Your activism, although self-beneficial is admirable, but we also do not solicit co-actors in questions. Removed these parts.

Answer (score 4):

[Piper](https://github.com/libratbag/piper/) supports the G915 and provides some level of support for macros. There are apparently issues with <kbd>G1</kbd> and <kbd>G2</kbd>, but those can be configured using [`ratbagctl`](https://github.com/libratbag/libratbag/); [for example, configuring <kbd>G1</kbd> as <kbd>1</kbd>](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxhardware/comments/k76ruy/remarks_on_the_logitech_g915_with_ubuntu_2004/) can be done using

```
ratbagctl "Logitech G915 WIRELESS RGB MECHANICAL GAMING KEYBOARD" profile 0 button 0 action set macro KEY_1
```

Another possible solution is [Input Remapper](https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper/), which provides generic macro support.